# Degeneracy when doing a change of variables in the partition function

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, partition-function

Suppose I'm computing the partition function of some system -an Ising Model, for example-

\begin{equation}
\sum_{x_1,...,\ x_N}e^{-\beta H(x_1,...,\ x_N)}
\end{equation}

and I want to make a change of variables $\{x_1,...,\ x_N \}\rightarrow \{y_1,...,\ y_M \}$ where the $y_i$ are functions of the previous variables and $N$ and $M$ can be different. In general, how do I know if I have to add a degeneracy factor $g(y_1,...,\ y_M)$

\begin{equation}
\sum_{x_1,...,\ x_N}e^{-\beta H(x_1,...,\ x_N)}= \sum_{y_1,...,\ y_M}g(y_1,...,\ y_M)e^{-\beta H(y_1,...,\ y_M)}
\end{equation}

Is there a formal way to know if $\sum_{x_1,...,\ x_N}=\sum_{y_1,...,\ y_M}$ or if I have to add the degeneracy $g$?

My guess is that if the change of variables is inversible then you don't need the degeneracy $g$ but I wouldn't know how to justify this either.

Comment: Let me write $y=(y_1,\dots,y_M)$, $x=(x_1,\dots,x_N)$, $y=f(x)$ and $H(x)=\tilde H(y)$. Then, you can write $\sum_{x} e^{-\beta H(x)} = \sum_{x} \bigl(\sum_{y}  1_{y=f(x)}\bigr) e^{-\beta H(x)} = \sum_{y} e^{-\beta \tilde H(y)} \sum_{x} 1_{y = f(x)}$. Now, if $f$ is a bijection, the last sum has only one nonzero term, and is thus equal to $1$. In general, the last sum produces the degeneracy factor you denote by $g$ above.

Comment: Hello! thanks for the comment. I don't understand what does 1_{y=f(x)} mean

Comment: It denotes an indicator function: $1_{y=f(x)}$ is equal to $1$ if $y=f(x)$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: great! I believe this could count as an answer... if you have the time to write it down properly I'd definetively vote it. Thanks anyway!

Comment: In my particular problem $x=(x_1, ... , x_N)$ and $y=f(x)=(x_1, x_1 x_2, x_2 x_3, ... , x_{N-1}x_{N})$ is that $f(x)$ biyective? I can't see it that easily.

Comment: Yes, it is bijective, since you can recover $x$ from $y$: $x_1=y_1$, $x_2=y_1y_2$ (since $y_1y_2 = x_1^2x_2=x_2$) and, in the same way, $x_k=y_{k-1}y_k$ for all $k>2$. (I am obviously assuming Ising spins.)

Comment: that is exactly my doubt, what if the variables x are general spins and can take values $x= -S, -S+1, ..., S-1, S$? then the bijection gets a little more obscure...

Comment: Well, if $S$ is an integer, then observe that both $x=(0,1,0,0,\dots,0)$ and $x=(0,0,0,\dots,0)$ lead to $y=(0,0,0,\dots,0)$. So, you don't have a bijection. If $S$ is a half-integer, but not an integer, then you can always recover $x$ by $x_1=y_1$ and $x_k=y_k/x_{k-1}$ for $k>1$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58009/discussion-between-p-c-spaniel-and-yvan-velenik).